# Remove duplicates from list

Tags: list, haskell, combinators

I have datatype:

```
data SidesType = Sides Int Int Int deriving (Show)
```

And I need a function which get a list of SidesType and remove duplicates from it.

```
*Main> let a = [Sides 3 4 5,Sides 3 4 5,Sides 5 12 13,Sides 6 8 10,Sides 6 8 10,Sides 8 15 17,Sides 9 12 15,Sides 5 12 13,Sides 9 12 15,Sides 12 16 20,Sides 8 15 17,Sides 15 20 25,Sides 12 16 20,Sides 15 20 25]
*Main> removeDuplicateFromList [] a
[Sides 3 4 5,Sides 5 12 13,Sides 6 8 10,Sides 6 8 10,Sides 8 15 17,Sides 9 12 15,Sides 5 12 13,Sides 9 12 15,Sides 12 16 20,Sides 8 15 17,Sides 15 20 25,Sides 12 16 20,Sides 15 20 25]
```

Here is my solution:

```
removeElementFromList :: [SidesType] -> SidesType -> [SidesType]
removeElementFromList lst element  = 
                      let (Sides a b c) = element
                      in [(Sides x y z) | (Sides x y z) <- lst, (x /= a) || (y /= b)]

removeDuplicateFromList :: [SidesType] -> [SidesType] -> [SidesType]
removeDuplicateFromList inlist outlist 
                        | (length outlist) == 0 = inlist
                        | otherwise = 
                          let element = head outlist
                              b = tail outlist
                              filtered = removeElementFromList b element
                      in removeDuplicateFromList (inlist ++ [element]) filtered
```

I am just wondering if there is any other way to write this code in more haskell-way ?

Comment: `(length outlist) == 0` -> `null outlist`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usual there is "By" function which adds flexibility:

```
nubBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

PS Although it's O(n^2)

Answer (score 3):

You're already deriving `Show` for your datatype. If you also derive `Eq`, you can use `nub` from `module Data.List`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Data.List.nub

Comment: I don't find how to use it with custom datatype. And I check only 2 of three members of type: (x /= a) || (y /= b)

Comment: Then nubBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]

Comment: Or wrap in a newtype! So much more elegant than using nubBy ;)

Comment: This is really an answer, not a comment to the question. Please use "Data.List.nub" to remove duplicate items from a list.

Answer (score 0):

First derive the order class also:

```
data XYZ = XYZ .... deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Or write your on Eq instance:

```
instance Eq XYZ where
a == b = ...
```

Then be intelligent and use a Tree! [Computer Science Trees grow from top to bottom!][1]

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

removeDuplicates ::[a] -> [a]
removeDuplicates list = map fst $ Map.toList $ Map.fromList $ map (\a -> (a,a)) list
```

Complexity (from right to left) for list with length N:

1. map of the list: O(N)
2. Map.fromList: O(N*log N)
3. Map.toList: O(log N)
4. map over list with list length smaller or equal to N: O(N)

They are called consecutively, this means, there are pluses between the complexities of the parts => O(2 * N + N * log N + log N) = O(N * log N)

This is way better than traversing N^2 times over the list!
See: [wolframAlpha plots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20n%20%2a%20log%20n;%20n%5E2%20;%202%2an;%20from%20n%20=0%20to%20n=50). I included 2*N also for comparison reasons.

2+3: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html

[1]:  Search wikipedia for Computer Science Tree

Comment: I'd hesitate to give a type like `XYZ` an `Ord` instance, just to speed up this algorithm – any such instance should also make sense conceptually! You can achieve the same complexity by staying with lists and using `map head . group . sortBy adHocOrd` instead of `nub`, with an "inline definition" of your proposed `Ord` instance. Or, if you really care about performance, define a `Hashable` instance instead: with a hashmap, you can get this down to _O_ (_n_)!

Comment: well, yeah the Hashtable makes sense of course. I didn't know about that package before...(well I actually I didn't know about the primitive package, which are needed by arrays and such).

But what's so bad about the Ord instance? At least if it is a type that does have some partial ordering defined, that shouldn't be any problem. Or am I wrong?

Btw: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: There are quite a few types where you _could_ define a partial ordering, but not a _canonical one_, in the sense that there would be an obvious mathematical unambiguous interpretation of it. Typical examples are the [complex numbers](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Complex.html#t:Complex), as well as any vector type (where any `Ord` instance would need to exploit some particular basis, but often there are multiple different ones that might be reasonable). And what the OP has looks quite vector-like indeed.